# Using thrift in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, thrift

I have thrift protocol and a simple app in angular2. I generate .js files with `thrift --gen js:ts file.thrift`.

How could i use thrift in angular2 app?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking.Thrift produces normal code that can be included into your project like any other code, there is nothing special so far. What problems do you experiencing?.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how 'Thrift' works but you have Angular-CLI for Angular2 applications.

https://cli.angular.io/